# Promise doesn't work in Javascript, Returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, parse-platform, promise

I want to fetch data from Parse.com and trigger a event after all Data has been loaded.
The methods `getEinstellerData`,`getObjektData` and `getVermieterData` contain the asynchronous query to the parse.com database. The Object within the queries are retreived correctly.

I wrote that code accordring to: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/

My problem now is, that the parameter of `var combinedPromise = $.when(getVermieterData(vermieterId), getEinstellerData(einstellerId));` which i actually wrote in the first promise to global variables, seem to be undefined.

I've got the following function to fetch Data:

```
getData = function() {

        var promise = getObjektData();

        promise.done(
            function(){

                var combinedPromise = $.when(getVermieterData(vermieterId), getEinstellerData(einstellerId));
                combinedPromise.done(function(){

                    console.log(einstellerData);
                    console.log(vermieterData);

                    $(that).trigger("setWohnungsDetails");
                });
            });

    },
```

these are the 3 Functions which contain the queries:

```
getEinstellerData = function(){
    einstellerData = [];

    var queryEinsteller = new Parse.Query(erstellerDataObject);

    queryEinsteller.equalTo("ID", parseInt(einstellerId));

    queryEinsteller.first({
      success: function(einsteller) {

        var vorname = einsteller.get("Vorname");
        var nachname = einsteller.get("Nachname");
        var strasse = einsteller.get("Strasse");
        var hausnummer = einsteller.get("Hausnummer");
        var plz = einsteller.get("PLZ");
        var ort = einsteller.get("Ort");
        var email = einsteller.get("Email");
        var telefon = einsteller.get("Telefon");

        einstellerData.push({ vorname: vorname, nachname: nachname, strasse: strasse, hausnummer: hausnummer, plz: plz, ort: ort, email: email, telefon: telefon });

        console.log(einstellerData);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
},

getVermieterData = function(){
    vermieterData = [];

    var queryVermieter = new Parse.Query(vermieterDataObject);

    queryVermieter.equalTo("ID", parseInt(vermieterId));

    queryVermieter.first({
      success: function(vermieter) {

        var vorname = vermieter.get("Vorname");
        var nachname = vermieter.get("Nachname");
        var strasse = vermieter.get("Strasse");
        var hausnummer = vermieter.get("Hausnummer");
        var plz = vermieter.get("PLZ");
        var ort = vermieter.get("Ort");
        var email = vermieter.get("Email");
        var telefon = vermieter.get("Telefon");

        vermieterData.push({ vorname: vorname, nachname: nachname, strasse: strasse, hausnummer: hausnummer, plz: plz, ort: ort, email: email, telefon: telefon });

        console.log(vermieterData);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
},

getObjektData = function() {

    objectId = localStorage.getItem("currentWohnung");

    objektData = [];

    var queryObjekt = new Parse.Query(objektDataObject);

    queryObjekt.get(objectId, {
      success: function(wohnung) {

        var vermieter_id = wohnung.get("Vermieter_id");
        var einsteller_id = wohnung.get("Einsteller_id");
        var strasse = wohnung.get("Strasse");
        var hausnummer = wohnung.get("Hausnummer");
        var plz = wohnung.get("PLZ");
        var ort = localStorage.getItem("selectedStadt");
        var bild = wohnung.get("Bild");
        var flaeche = wohnung.get("Flaeche");
        var freitext = wohnung.get("Freitext");
        var gesamtmiete = wohnung.get("Gesamtmiete");
        var kaution = wohnung.get("Kaution");
        var miete = wohnung.get("Miete");
        var nebenkosten = wohnung.get("Nebenkosten");
        var raucher = wohnung.get("Raucher");
        var zimmer = wohnung.get("Zimmer");


        objektData.push({ vermieter_id: vermieter_id, einsteller_id: einsteller_id, strasse: strasse, hausnummer: hausnummer, plz: plz, ort: ort, bild: bild, flaeche: flaeche, freitext: freitext, gesamtmiete: gesamtmiete, kaution: kaution, nebenkosten:nebenkosten, raucher: raucher, zimmer: zimmer });

        console.log(objektData);

        einstellerId = einsteller_id;
        vermieterId = vermieter_id;
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
        console.log("error" + error);
      }
    });
```

And here my console output:

```
DetailStart init DetailStart.js:3
DetailController init DetailController.js:10
init Detail.js Detail.js:17
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined Detail.js:34
DetailStart.Detail.getData Detail.js:34
DetailStart.Detail.init Detail.js:21
DetailStart.DetailController.init DetailController.js:13
DetailStart.init DetailStart.js:4
(anonymous function) detail.html:115
[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Any idea what I might have gotten wrong here!?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: `promise` is undefined because you never set it equal to anything. `getObjektData` doesn't return anything.

Comment: depends on what you're trying to do...

Comment: None of those functions have anything remotely close to a promise object, you'll have to create and resolve your own promises.

Comment: And the error you are getting is happening here: `queryObjekt.get(` because `queryObjekt` is undefined.

Comment: First finish 'getObjektData' then finish 'getVermieterData' and 'getEinstellerData' and finally when all of the 3 functions are completely finished and the data writen to the global variables, I want the event to trigger.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

Comment: but first you have to fix `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined Detail.js:57` which has nothing to do with the promise you are trying to implement.

Comment: @KevinB I wish I could downvote comments. jQuery's Deferreds are not standard compliant Promises, and the author is mainly using pure JS for his code.

Comment: @Kroltan mainly yes, but he was trying to use jQuery's deferred/promise system incorrectly, which is what my comments are about.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, sorry, I've misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the libraries you are using but it looks like you are mixing callbacks and promises which can be used together but you have to be careful. For example,

```
queryEinsteller.first({ 
   ...
});
```

will return immediately causing the `combinedPromise` to be resolved before `success` or `error` members are called. What you need to do is create a promise that is resolved when `success` or `error` is called. You can then return that promise from `getEinstellerData`. You need to do the same thing in `getVermieterData`.

For an example of how to do this you should study the example in the section entitled "Putting it together with $.Deferred" in the web page you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `queryObject.get(..)` will return a promise, if you want to allow chaining then you need to return that value from your functions, i.e.

```
getObjektData = function() {
    // .. other code ..
    return queryObjekt.get(objectId, {
        success: /* .. your success handler .. */
        error: /* .. your errror handler .. */
    });
};
```

Basically just add that **return** statement to your call, do the same in your other functions.

The question is do you want the first query to finish before you start the second, and same for third vs second (i.e. following queries require data from prior queries), or do you want all three to be started and just do something when they're all done?

I'll update this question with samples once you answer that question for me.

Comment: I want the 'getObjektData' to finish first, because it retreives the ids for the objekts I want to get from the other 2 queries. These 2 may happen simultaniously.